# property-set is not setting value

Tags: pega

I am trying to set 'emailid' value from table records into a property and then pass this property as input to 'To' in sendemailnotification method. When i run tracer, parameter is not being set, it is empty, so i get message saying atleast one emailid is required(to or cc or bcc).

I can see once the when rule in property-set is being validated, property values is not set, it is directly going to child item which is call sendemailnotification. 'To' is empty:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

got this. Solved this by adding ".Emailid" also in the Obj-Browse.